# Инфинитив - какой вид сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис

Если сказуемое выражено инфинитивом, то каким его считать, если не простым глагольным сказуемым (чтобы добиться цели...)?

Comment: Нужно рассматривать в конкретных примерах. Приведите их.

Comment: Чтобы добиться цели, надо много трудиться.

Answer (score 2):

**ДЛЯ ШКОЛЫ**

**Чем может быть инфинитив в сказуемом:**

(1) *Он хотел **добиться цели***  — составное глагольное сказуемое.

(2) *Ему нужно **добиться цели***  — примыкающий инфинитив в роли дополнения в безличном предложении, сказуемое составное именное (нужно добиться, было нужно добиться).

(3) *Нужно много работать, чтобы **добиться цели.***

Можно считать, что это **составное именное** сказуемое, именная часть выражена инфинитивом, нулевая связка. Но в учебнике об этом не говорится, да и детям понять сложно.

(4) **ПГС? Стр. 68**

**Примечание.** Иногда к простому глагольному сказуемому относят случаи вида: *Люди — пахать, а мы — руками махать.*

В большинстве таких случаев отчетливо ощущается **пропуск второго глагола,** что придает предложению большую экспрессивность: Так вы бунтовать?! (Так вы **вздумали I намерены I решили** бунтовать)] Кто куда, а я обедать (а я иду I **отправляюсь** обедать)

(5) **Упрощенный вариант** мог бы выглядеть как пропуск модальной связки: Чтобы можно было добиться цели...
Но в этом случае лучше считать, что **это СГС**, а **модальная** связка пропущена.

**ИНФИНИТИВНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ**

***Чтобы добиться цели...***

1. Это придаточное предложение, **односоставное, инфинитивное.**
2. **Главный член** инфинитивных предложений выражен **независимым инфинитивом.**

Указание **на субъекта действия**, обозначенного инфинитивом, не входит в грамматическую основу. Но поскольку действия, о которых сообщается в инфинитивных предложениях, подразумевают субъекта, то **информация о нем** в том или ином виде присутствует в предложении.

**Субъект** может выражаться **формой Д. п.**: Тебе дежурить; может быть **понятен из ситуации**: Встать! (требование к присутствующим); может иметь **обобщенное значение**: Как варить грибной суп (рецепт).

3. **Инфинитив широко используется** в вопросительных предложениях {Как пройти в библиотеку?), а также в сложных предложениях для выражения различных модальных значений — **в придаточном цели: Пришел, чтобы поговорить;** в придаточном условия: Если бы с ним поговорить, я уверен, что он резко изменился бы (Б.); в придаточном времени: Прежде чем сдавать экзамен, надо подготовиться.

**[Из вузовского учебника по синтаксису, стр. 92](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)**

Comment: А как в школе их называть? В школьном учебнике ничего об этом нет, а встречаются они часто. Дети пишут, что это ПГС, т.к. состоит из одного глагола.

Comment: Я дополнила ответ по возможности. Но этот вопрос в школьной педагогике решается, со специалистами надо консультироваться.

Comment: Не каждая грамматическая форма однозначно укладывается в принятую классификацию. Переходные зоны,  и все такое)  Ирреальная модальность есть? Пусть будет СГС (в школе).  У Кустовой парадигма указана при отрицании:  Здесь не пройти / было не пройти / было бы не пройти.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос. Вот [тут](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#44) говорят, что инфинитив подчинен союзу **чтобы**.
То есть отвечает на вопрос чтобы что? Но союзы не бывают значащими членами синтаксической структуры, как тогда подчиненный союзу объект может быть значащим членом? Противоречие.

Вообще же это известная конструкция обстоятельства цели.

> Завтра пойдем на делянку (для чего?) набрать душистой лесной малины.

Здесь инфинитив не является сказуемым, а будет обстоятельством.

Почему же тогда тут он должен быть сказуемым??

> Завтра пойдем на делянку (для чего?) чтобы набрать душистой лесной малины.

Comment: Это называется синтаксическая синонимия. Разная грамматика для одного значения. Никакого вывода при сравнении  не сделать, кроме как по семантике.   И потом разбор должен быть одинаковым для всех предложений с инфинитивом, а не только для союза чтобы.  Вот в моем тексте "не сделать" какое сказуемое?

Comment: нечего было ждать, никаких выводов было не сделать. Это особая трехзвенная структура у кустовой разбираются эти отрицательные предложения. Но чтобы здесь не при чем.

Comment: Видела я эти предложения, называются безлично-инфинитивные. Но какой ваш ответ: как в школе разбирать? Нужно выбрать один из трех вариантов. Что больше подходит? Пусть высокая наука поможет школьникам в решении практической задачи)